# Get the Type of a Parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, types, parent, decltype

Given the following classes:

```
template <typename T>
class Child : public T {};
```

I also have a templatized function:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& bar)
```

After doing some template gymnastics I have a section of code that has determined that `bar` is a `Child` of some sort. But I need to find of *what* sort.

I want to be able to make a call on `bar` that yields the type inherited. So fake syntax to find the type of `Parent` would be:

```
decltype(foo.parent) bar;
```

Is there any actual syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: and if child inherits from both parent1 and parent2?

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to achieve by such a declaration? It might help with giving you more direction on how to do something of the sort.

Comment: ... and if it's `Child : Parent : Grandparent`?

Comment: LOL, and if its decltype(int.parent)? as you can see, it has no ends

Comment: @DavidHaim I didn't think of that, I guess I have to use good old `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: or std::is_base_of + std::is_same

Comment: @Shrewd `Child foo` has a templatized parent. I'm trying to instantiate an object of it's parent type, but I need to keep the code generic, so using a bunch of `dynamic_cast`s is undesirable.

Comment: @JonathanMee Please post that specific example in your question.

Comment: @Barry I've clarified the question as much as I'm able, but it's difficult to descramble the code into an easy to understand format. Suffice to say I have a `Child` and I'd like to know what it inherits from.

Comment: Since `Child` and its siblings seem to be under your control, can't you just add a nested type to them - `using parent = T;`? Then, in `foo`, you use `typename T::parent`. Or, well, `typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(bar)>::parent`.

Comment: @bogdan Hmmm... At least `Child` is under my control, so it does seem like I could do a `typedef` or something to retain the parent type...

Comment: @JonathanMee For types that aren't under your control, if the set of types is known, a type trait also seems like a solution.

Comment: @bogdan There doesn't seem to be a better answer than this, and I've noticed that this is how the standard handles it. All the standard containers define the template arguments that they take. Can you add this as an answer, I'd like to accept it.

Comment: @JonathanMee Done. If you think more details on the type trait alternative would be useful, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the OP, here's an expanded version of my comment above:

One common way of handling this if `Child` and its siblings are under your control is to add a nested type to them:

```
template<typename T> class Child : public T 
{
public:
   using parent = T;
};

template<typename T> void foo(const T& bar)
{
   typename T::parent goo;
}
```

If `T` is not directly available (in a lambda, for example), then this should work:

```
auto foo2 = [](const auto& bar)
{
   typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(bar)>::parent goo;
};
```

To make it slightly nicer and shorter,

```
template<typename T> using parent = typename T::parent;

template<typename T> void foo(const T& bar)
{
   parent<T> goo;
}

auto foo2 = [](const auto& bar)
{
   parent<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(bar)>> goo;
};
```

(Although `parent` is a relatively common name; beware of clashes. `parent_t`, maybe?)

For types that aren't under your control, if the set of types is known, `parent<T>` could also be an external type trait.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the type as your argument:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const Child<T>& bar) {

}
```

`bar` is a `Child` that inherits from `T`. You can even add a separate overload for non-`Child`:

```
template <typename NonChild>
void foo(const NonChild& baz) { }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I originally had, but I need the function to be able to accept other types as well, not just `Child`. (I know this thing is in need of a rewrite, but till I can get to that;) is there anything that can be done outside of just accepting the type as a function parameter?

Comment: @JonathanMee That's what the overload is for. Otherwise, clarify what you want to do such that you want one function that needs the `T` in `Child<T>` *and* works for non-Child.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the right solution. I'm gonna hold for a bit before I accept though in hopes someone has some other magic.