# How to get type of smart pointer in macros?

Tags: c++, pointers, macros, smart-pointers, decltype

This line is too long:

```
btnNickname = TWeakObjectPtr<UButton>(Cast<UButton>(WidgetTree->FindWidget(FName(STRINGIFY(btnNickname))));
```

For a variable defined as:

```
TWeakObjectPtr<UButton> btnNickname;
```

I want to create macro for reduce the code:

```
FIND_WIDGET(btnNickname);
```

There are any way to do it?

I use this code now:

```
#define FIND_WIDGET(TYPE, NAME) NAME = TWeakObjectPtr<TYPE>(Cast<TYPE>(WidgetTree->FindWidget(FName(STRINGIFY(NAME)))))
```

But macro has two parameters. Can I get the pointer type from a `TWeakObjectPtr` variable?
The `decltype` can give me type of variable, but not type of data of pointer.

Substance:

```
#define FIND_WIDGET(NAME) NAME = TWeakObjectPtr<decltype(*NAME)>(Cast<decltype(*NAME)>(WidgetTree->FindWidget(FName(STRINGIFY(NAME)))))
```

But this not works.

P.S. [`TWeakObjectPtr`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Core/UObject/TWeakObjectPtr/index.html) is smart pointer used in Unreal Engine 4.

Comment: White space (including new lines) are free! Use them instead of macros

Comment: I am not familiar with Unreal smart pointer, but smart pointers generally have the type of the object they manage defined within. So you should be able to get it from the type of the pointer.

Comment: I had a similar question about extracting a type from a templatized object: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31429363/2642059 The accepted answer there points out that the C++ standard classes provide `typedefs` which are defined as the template arguments so they can be referenced later. Perhaps `TWeakObjectPtr` has a similar `typedef`?

Comment: Macros suck. Just say no.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I almost universally agree with you but, I have to say that for debug purposes `STRINGIFY` can be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, but that's not an excuse to create a new one that does something unnecessary and obfuscates the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect the reason it doesn't work is that `decltype(*NAME)` is a reference type, so you'd need to strip the reference:

```
std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*NAME)>
```

Or you might be able to do:

```
std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(NAME.operator->())>
```

But you shouldn't be using a macro anyway. Macros smell and parents will point at you and tell their children not to go near the bad man who uses macros. Write C++, not macros.

The compiler can easily deduce the type of the object:

```
template<typename T>
  inline void
  find_widget(TWeakObjectPtr<T>& t, const char* name)
  {
    t = TWeakObjectPtr<T>(Cast<T>(WidgetTree->FindWidget(FName(name))));
  }
```

And then:

```
find_widget(foo, STRINGIFY(foo));
```

This is more flexible because you can also do:

```
find_widget(foo, "something else");
```

N.B. `find_widget` doesn't seem like a very good name for something that modifies its argument.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response! Very helpful info.
I will not use the macro and use this template.

And what about better name for this function? :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to extract the type from the smart pointer might be (untested):

```
template<typename T> struct Untweaker;
template<typename T> struct Untweaker<TWeakObjectPtr<T>> {
  using type = T;
}
template<typename T> using Untweak = typename Untweaker<T>::type;
```

Then you can use `Untweak<decltype(variable)>` to extract the actual type.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename T>
TWeakObjectPtr<T> FindWidgetHelper(
    TWidgetTree* tree, const char* name, TWeakObjectPtr<T> widget) {
  return TWeakObjectPtr<T>(Cast<T>(tree->FindWidget(FName(name))));
}

#define FIND_WIDGET(NAME) \
NAME = FindWidgetHelper(WidgetTree, STRINGIFY(NAME), NAME)
```

Adjust to taste. I'm not at all familiar with Unreal Engine, and had to take a few guesses at the types of various things.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`TWeakObjectPtr::GetEvenIfUnreachable`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Core/UObject/TWeakObjectPtr/GetEvenIfUnreachable/index.html) to find the type of an given `TWeakObjectPtr` like this:

```
remove_pointer_t<decltype(btnNickname.GetEvenIfUnreachable())>
```

[[Simplified Example](http://ideone.com/EWUxPd)]

So basically just plug that into your already existing macro:

```
#define FIND_WIDGET(NAME) NAME = TWeakObjectPtr<remove_pointer_t<decltype(NAME.GetEvenIfUnreachable())>>(Cast<remover_pointer_t<decltype(NAME.GetEvenIfUnreachable())>>(WidgetTree->FindWidget(FName(STRINGIFY(NAME)))))
```

Full disclosure I had to ask to figure out how to get these types: [Getting the Return Type of a Templatized Object's Method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32910315/2642059)