# Getting the Return Type of a Templatized Object's Method

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, return-type, result-of

Say that I have:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    T& func();
};
```

And I implement a `Foo`: `Foo<int> bar` Now I want to get the return type of `bar.func()`. I've been trying to force [`result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) to work with me but to no avail.

What I'd really like is to just be able to do `result_of_t<foo.func>` and be done with it but I imagine it's significantly more difficult? How should I go about getting this return type?

**EDIT:**
I was hoping to accomplish this without without respect to how `bar` was declared. That is to say, I want to just be able to pass `bar.func` into `result_of` or similar and gt out the return type.

Comment: Do you have an example of what is not working?

Comment: @Barry has given you a solution, and you can just template the using declaration to account for any `Foo<T>`. You would then have to call `decltype( <variable_name> )` whenever you used it to provide the template parameter.

Comment: @bku_drytt I think you're answering the question I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910315/getting-the-return-type-of-a-templatized-objects-method#comment53649902_32910421). But if I do: `result_of_t<decltype(&(decltype(bar)::func))(decltype(bar)&)>` I get the error: "error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'"

Comment: @JonathanMee You have extra parens. Just `decltype(&decltype(bar)::func)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) is pretty annoying to use actually. Its syntax is:

```
 result_of<F(ArgTypes...)>
```

Where `F` is something invokable, and everything here is a type. In your case, you want to invoke a member function: `&Foo<int>::func`. But it's not the *value* of the pointer-to-member that you need, but the type. So we want `decltype(&Foo<int>::func)`. The way to invoke a member function is to pass an instance of the object as the first argument.

Put it all together and we get:

```
using T = std::result_of_t<decltype(&Foo<int>::func)(Foo<int>&)>;
static_assert(std::is_same<T, int&>::value, "!");
```

Or we could just use `decltype`:

```
using T = decltype(std::declval<Foo<int>&>().func());
```

which is much more natural.

---

Given `bar`, that's just:

```
using T = decltype(bar.func());
```

as opposed to:

```
using T = std::result_of_t<decltype(&decltype(bar)::func)(decltype(bar))>;
```

Comment: This is a good answer cause I didn't specify in the question, but if I didn't know the templatized type of `bar` is there a way to do this? Hopefully that question made sense I'm asking about the case where `T` is unknown, but I have `bar`.

Comment: @JonathanMee So just `decltype(bar.func())`?

Comment: of course it would be that easy. I was just trying to do it with `result_of` thank you for helping me see the light.

Comment: Could you just add that to your answer? I'd like to accept it but I don't want anyone to miss it in the comments.

Comment: @JonathanMee Could you add to your question that that's what you actually wanted?