# Retrieve the template a type is instantiated from

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

How can I retrieve the template a type was originally instantiated from?

I'd like to do the following:

```
struct Baz{};
struct Bar{};

template <typename T>
struct Foo {};

using SomeType = Foo<Bar>;

template <typename T>
using Template = get_template<SomeType>::template type<T>;

static_assert(std::is_same<Foo<Baz>, Template<Baz>>::value, "");
```

I know I can achieve this through partial specialization, but this forces me to specialize `get_template` for every template I want to use it with:

```
template <typename T>
struct get_template;

template <typename T>
struct get_template<Foo<T>>
{
    template <typename X>
    using type = Foo<X>;
};
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4f9bb31daab3619)</kbd>

Is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the Type of a Parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429363/get-the-type-of-a-parent)

Comment: The example is a bit contrived because you're using aliases. "SomeType" is already the same as "Foo<Bar>" (`static_assert(std::is_same<SomeType, Foo<Bar>>::value, "");`). Perhaps you are actually looking to recover only the `Foo` portion because you'd like to instantiate it for another type?

Comment: @AndyG yes I'd eventually like to instantiate it with another type, I edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like that, using a [template template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter) (should work for templates with any number of **type** arguments):

```
template <typename T>
  struct get_template;

template <template <class...> class Y, typename... Args>
  struct get_template<Y<Args...>> {
    template <typename... Others>
    using type = Y<Others...>;
  };
```

Then to get the template:

```
template <typename T>
using Template = typename get_template<SomeType>::type<T>;
```

As mentioned by @Yakk in the comment, the above only works for template that only have type arguments. You can specialize for template with specific pattern of type and non-type arguments, e.g.:

```
// Note: You need the first size_t to avoid ambiguity with the first specialization
template <template <class, size_t, size_t...> class Y, typename A, size_t... Sizes>
  struct get_template<Y<A, Sizes...>> {
    template <class U, size_t... OSizes>
    using type = Y<U, OSizes...>;
  };
```

...but you will not be able to specialize it for arbitrary templates.

---

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/g/6duVKj) (with `Foo` and `std::pair`):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>

struct Bar{};

template <typename T>
struct Foo {};

using SomeType = Foo<Bar>;

template <typename T>
  struct get_template;

template <template <class...> class Y, typename... Args>
  struct get_template<Y<Args...>> {
    template <typename... Others>
    using type = Y<Others...>;
  };

template <typename T>
using Template = typename get_template<SomeType>::type<T>;

static_assert(std::is_same<SomeType, Template<Bar>>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<Foo<int>, Template<int>>::value, "");

using PairIntInt = std::pair<int, int>;
using PairIntDouble = std::pair<int, double>;

template <typename U1, typename U2>
using HopeItIsPair = 
  typename get_template<PairIntDouble>::type<U1, U2>;

static_assert(std::is_same<PairIntDouble, HopeItIsPair<int, double>>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<PairIntInt, HopeItIsPair<int, int>>::value, "");
```

Comment: Naturally, this only works for templates that only take types, or for a finite pattern of templates.

Comment: @Yakk Yes... I don't think there is a way to make it work for any kind of templates (especially if you have interleaving type and non-type parameters). Nonetheless, if you have some information about the template argument pattern, you can easily adapt the above code to match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got the question. Would this work?

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

template<typename V, template<typename> class T, typename U>
auto get_template(T<U>) { return T<V>{}; }

struct Baz{};
struct Bar{};

template <typename T>
struct Foo {};

using SomeType = Foo<Bar>;

template <typename T>
using Template = decltype(get_template<T>(SomeType{}));

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<Foo<Baz>, Template<Baz>>::value, "");
}
```

You can generalize even more (`SomeType` could be a template parameter of `Template`, as an example), but it gives an idea of what the way is.