# In C++ template meta programming, how do you return a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

```
template <template <typename...> typename T, template <typename...> typename U>
struct is_same_template : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> typename T>
struct is_same_template<T, T> : std::true_type {};

template <template <typename...> typename T, template <typename...> typename U>
constexpr bool is_same_template_v = is_same_template<T, U>::value;
```

The above implementation of `is_same_template` can cause the two statements below to compile.

```
static_assert(is_same_template_v<std::map, std::map>);
static_assert(!is_same_template_v<std::map, std::vector>);
```

Is it possible to enhance the `is_same_template` such that the following statements will compile?

```
static_assert(is_same_template_v<std::map<int, bool>, std::map>);
static_assert(is_same_template_v<std::map<int, bool>, std::map<int, int>>);
static_assert(!is_same_template_v<std::map<int, bool>, std::vector>);
static_assert(!is_same_template_v<std::map<int, bool>, std::vector<int>>);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `static_assert(is_same_template_v<std::map, std::map>);` can compile without any error?

Comment: do you really want to mix templates and types? What would be the use of this mixing? What i mean is that I'd rather use your `is_same_template` and a different trait `is_instantiation_of`

Comment: @Yves why not? https://godbolt.org/z/qd7qeTeWr

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ohh... I used a very old compiler..

Answer (score 5):

Since the template parameter of the template class is fixed, you cannot define a template class that is also named `is_same_template` but accepts different template parameters, instead, you need to redefine the template class but reuse `is_same_template`, that is, use template partial specialization to get the template template parameter and pass it to `is_same_template`.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same_template2 : std::false_type {};

template<
  template <typename...> typename T, typename... TArgs,
  template <typename...> typename U, typename... UArgs>
struct is_same_template2<T<TArgs...>, U<UArgs...>> : is_same_template<T, U> {};

template <typename T, template <typename...> typename U>
struct is_same_template3 : std::false_type {};

template <
  template <typename...> typename T, typename... TArgs,
  template <typename...> typename U>
struct is_same_template3<T<TArgs...>, U> : is_same_template<T, U> {};
```

In order to unify the interface, you can overload different template functions and use the corresponding implementation

```
template <template <typename...> typename T, template <typename...> typename U>
constexpr bool same_template() {
  return is_same_template<T, U>();
}

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool same_template() {
  return is_same_template2<T, U>();
}

template <typename T, template <typename...> typename U>
constexpr bool same_template() {
  return is_same_template3<T, U>();
}
```

Then you can invoke like this

```
static_assert(same_template<std::map, std::map>());
static_assert(!same_template<std::map, std::vector>());
static_assert(same_template<std::map<int, bool>, std::map>());
static_assert(same_template<std::map<int, bool>, std::map<int, int>>());
static_assert(!same_template<std::map<int, bool>, std::vector>());
static_assert(!same_template<std::map<int, bool>, std::vector<int>>());
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dvcTbxxMx)

Comment: Is there any magic to implementing `get_template` to make a flowing statement compile?
`static_assert(is_same_template_v<get_template<std::map<int, bool>>, std::map>);`

Comment: I'm afraid not, you [can extract the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992250/retrieve-the-template-a-type-is-instantiated-from), but that won't work because it's not the original template.